# event.currentTarget.parentNode.remove(); not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to learn stuff I was used to doing in jQuery in plain JavaScript.

I have an example I found on the internet to solve, which gave me a hard time.

I am trying to remove the parent div. single on click on the button. remove.

Here is the code;

```
<div class="row" id="showAward">

</div>
<div class="w-100 text-center">
    <a id="add" class="bg-primary text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
    </a>
</div>

<script>
    let count = 0;

    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (event.target.id === 'add') {
            count++;
            addAward(count);
        }
        if (event.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
            event.currentTarget.parentNode.remove();
        }
    });
    function addAward(number) {
        let html = `<div class="col-lg-4 mb-3 position-relative">
            <label for="image${number}" class="form-label">image ${number}</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image${number}" name="image${number}">
            <a class="delete text-danger cursor-pointer position-absolute end-0 top-0"><i class="fa-solid fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>`;
        document.getElementById('showAward').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: event.currentTarget is the element that the click listener was assigned to (the document).  Not sure why you didn't stick with event.target there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Event`'s `currentTarget` getter will return the `EventTarget` in the bubbling chain where the event is being dispatched at the current phase.
It will change dynamically and when gotten synchronously from a callback to `EventTarget.addEventListener()`, it will be the `EventTarget` on which you called `addEventListener()` (which makes it similar to `this` in this regard).

```js
const parent = document.querySelector(".parent");
const child = document.querySelector(".child");

const initialEvent = new Event("foobar", { bubbles: true });

let childEvent = null;
child.addEventListener("foobar", (evt) => {
  console.log("#### In child");
  childEvent = evt; // Store for later
  // It's actually the same object that is passed along
  console.log("initialEvent === evt", initialEvent === evt);
  console.log("evt.currentTarget", evt.currentTarget); // .child
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("#### In timeout from child");
    // currentTarget becomes null after the dispatch is done
    console.log("evt.currentTarget", evt.currentTarget);
  });
});
parent.addEventListener("foobar", (evt) => {
  console.log("#### In parent");
  // Still the same object
  console.log("initialEvent === evt", initialEvent === evt);
  console.log("evt.currentTarget", evt.currentTarget); // .parent
  console.log("childEvent.currentTarget", childEvent.currentTarget); // .parent
});

child.dispatchEvent(initialEvent);
console.log("#### After dispatch");
console.log("childEvent.currentTarget", childEvent.currentTarget); // null
```

```html
<div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
```

So in your case `currentTarget` in that context would the the `Document` node, because you did call `document.addEventListener()`.

Now, `.target` would represent the `EventTarget` on which the event has been dispatched, i.e. in case of a click, the element that did receive the click.
However, it may not be the one you were expecting. For instance in you case, clicking the `<i>` element that is inside the `.delete` one, would set the `.target` to that `<i>` element, and not to the `.delete` one and thus you'd miss the click.

Instead when delegating use `.closest()` to test if the element you're actually interested in is in the event chain. This method also returns the element in which it's been called in case it matches.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  console.log("target", evt.target);
  console.log("target is .delete", evt.target.classList.contains("delete"));
  const actualTarget = evt.target.closest(".delete");
  console.log("actualTarget", actualTarget);
});
```

```html
<span class="delete">
  <i>click me</i>
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like, when the event listener is on `document` the property curretnTarget is `undefined`. Use `event.target` instead. And then instead of using `parentNode` use the method [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest). You can give a CSS selector as a parameter to the method and get a parent element.

```js
let count = 0;

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id === 'add') {
    count++;
    addAward(count);
  }
  if (event.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
    event.target.closest('div.position-relative').remove();
  }
});

function addAward(number) {
  let html = `<div class="col-lg-4 mb-3 position-relative">
            <label for="image${number}" class="form-label">image ${number}</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image${number}" name="image${number}">
            <a class="delete text-danger cursor-pointer position-absolute end-0 top-0"><i class="fa-solid fa-times"></i>Delete</a>
        </div>`;
  document.getElementById('showAward').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="showAward">

</div>
<div class="w-100 text-center">
  <a id="add" class="bg-primary text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>Add
  </a>
</div>
```